# Unable to update json property using spread operator within this.setState() - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following is the simple react code containing two dropdowns to select `report type` and `date type` respectively. On selecting the each of the dropdowns, I try to update the respective single property (`metricsDropDown : reporType`, `dateDropDown:dateType`) in the `state` using spread operator. However the `reportType` is getting updated as `undefined` in `state`.

The code is given below:

```
class MetricsReport extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        metricsParams: {reportType: "", dateType: ""}
      }
      this.getReportType = this.getReportType.bind(this);
      this.getMetricsDateType = this.getMetricsDateType.bind(this);

    }
    getReportType(event) {
      console.log(this.state.metricsParams);
      const {value} = event.target.value;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        metricsParams: {
            ...prevState.metricsParams,
            reportType: value
        }
      }))

    }
    getMetricsDateType(event) {
      console.log('metricsparams:reportType', this.state.metricsParams.reportType); // reportType is undefined here
      const {value} = event.target.value;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        metricsParams: {
            ...prevState.metricsParams,
            dateType: value
        }
      }))
    }
    componentDidMount() {

    }

    render() {
      return (
          <div >
              <select id="metricsDropDown" className="browser-default" onChange={this.getReportType}>
                <option value="MetricsByContent">Metrics By Content</option>
                <option value="MetricsByUser">Metrics By User</option>
              </select>
              <select id="dateDropDown" className="browser-default" onChange={this.getMetricsDateType}>
                <option value="Publish Date">Publish Date</option>
                <option value="Expiry Date">Expiry Date</option>
                <option value="Read Date">Read Date</option>
              </select>
          </div>
      )
    }

}

export default MetricsReport;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Destructuring syntax is wrong. It expects `value` property to be an object with another `value` property.

It should be:

```
const {value} = event.target;
```